# Open sharepoint page with acces token

Tags: access-token, sharepoint-online

I am developing a SPA in react. When the user clicks on a button I would like to open a sharepoint page but without the user having to enter the username and password.

To do this the client makes a request to a server that gets the access token, I leave the code here

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class OfficeService {


@ConfigProperty(name = "microsoft.autenticacion.AUTHORITY")
String authority;

@ConfigProperty(name = "microsoft.autenticacion.CLIENT_ID")
String clientId;

@ConfigProperty(name = "microsoft.autenticacion.CLIENT_SECRET_ID")
String clientSecretId;

@ConfigProperty(name = "microsoft.autenticacion.CLIENT_SECRET_VALUE")
String clientSecretValue;
@ConfigProperty(name = "microsoft.autenticacion.SCOPE")
String scope;


private static ConfidentialClientApplication app;

public IAuthenticationResult getToken() throws Exception {
    try {
        BuildConfidentialClientObject();
        IAuthenticationResult result = getAccessTokenByClientCredentialGrant();
        return result;

    } catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Oops! We have an exception of type - " + ex.getClass());
        System.out.println("Exception message - " + ex.getMessage());
        throw ex;
    }
}

private void BuildConfidentialClientObject() throws Exception {

    // Load properties file and set properties used throughout the sample
    app = ConfidentialClientApplication.builder(
                    clientId,
                    ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret(clientSecretValue))
            .authority(authority)
            .build();
}

private IAuthenticationResult getAccessTokenByClientCredentialGrant() throws Exception {

    // With client credentials flows the scope is ALWAYS of the shape "resource/.default", as the
    // application permissions need to be set statically (in the portal), and then granted by a tenant administrator
    ClientCredentialParameters clientCredentialParam = ClientCredentialParameters.builder(
                    Collections.singleton(scope))
            .build();

    CompletableFuture<IAuthenticationResult> future = app.acquireToken(clientCredentialParam);
    return future.get();
}
```

}

Now with this token I would like to be able to open a sharepoint page.

with a window.open adding in the query param the token but it still asks me to enter username and password.

```
window.open(`https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/intranet/company/manufacturing/NC/SitePages/NC.aspx?token=${token}#/List`, '_blank');
```

Any help?

Thanks in advance